# Adding a class to link_to block with anchor

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, link-to

I'm trying to wrap an `'anchor' tag` around an `svg image` using the `link_to helper`. The `href` of the link is an anchor on the same page and it has to have a class. I followed the documentation's instructions and it works fine without the class. But when I add the class, it gets added to the `href` `(a href="/?class=test#section-1")`. I need it to render as this: `<a href="/section-1" class="logo-inclub">`.

This is the documentation that I'm following:

```
link_to(url, html_options = {}) do
  # name
end
```

This is my code (I'm using slim for the template):

```
= link_to(anchor: 'section-1' , class: 'logo-inclub')  do
   = svg_image("logo_inclub")
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanx!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question probably answer itself:

```
link_to(url, html_options = {}) do
  # name
end
```

So your link should be:

```
= link_to('/section-1' , class: 'logo-inclub' )  do
   = svg_image("logo_inclub")
```

Comment: Yup, that did it. I looked everywhere for the proper way to add an anchor tag as the URL and it always had it as: anchor => 'anchor text' or (like I had it in my example) anchor: 'anchor text'.
Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Believe me I tried, but it doesn't let me. I just signed up to this forum and I don't have enough rep points to be able to vote. Is there a workaround??

Answer (score 0):

Didn't you forget url?

```
= link_to("http://stackoverflow.com", anchor: 'section-1', class: 'logo-inclub')  do
   = svg_image("logo_inclub")
```